# WiFi Support for ASUS C201PA

Tags: networking, kernel, broadcom

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 with a Linux 4.16 kernel on my ASUS C201PA Chromebook, but I am unable to configure WiFi. All I did was grab the base-armhf image from the Ubuntu sources and uncompress them onto my USB device. Then, I cloned the RockMyy directory (https://github.com/Miouyouyou/RockMyy) and ran the script found there. After that, I signed the kernel and flashed to a partition of the USB. I'm not sure where to find the correct modules and firmware for my WiFi device. It seems my WiFi card is a Broadcom SDIO 4354 (device name 0x4354) based on some internet searches.

`dmesg | grep -i sdio` returns

`pwrseq_simple sdio-pwrseq: GPIO lookup for consumer reset
 pwrseq_simple sdio-pwrseq: using device tree for GPIO lookup
of_get_named_gpiod_flags: parsed 'reset-gpios' property of node '/sdio-pwrseg[0]' - status (0)
mmc1: new ultra high speed SDR104 SDIO card at address 0001
Bluetooth: Generic Bluetooth SDIO driver ver 0.1`

`lsusb` returns

`Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bc2:ab00 Seagate RSS LLC Slim Portable Drive
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f2:b53a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `dmesg | grep -i sdio` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Seems to mention nothing about WiFi, but posted output in question.

Comment: Let's dig deeper. Please show us: `dmesg | grep -e 4354 -e brcm`

Comment: It returns no output.

Comment: I'm running out of places to look! How about: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `lsusb`

Comment: lspci returns no output.

Comment: I'm very sorry but I can see no trace of your wireless device at all. I don't know what to suggest for a driver if I don't know what the device is.

Comment: Would you know where to find brcmfmac kernel modules or drivers? I was poking around with some different Linux distros on my Chromebook and found brcmfmac in the ones with WiFi.

Comment: In recent Ubuntu versions, they are included by default. Confirm: `modinfo brcmfmac` If you load the module and check the log, are there any informative clues? `sudo modprobe brcmfmac && dmesg | grep brcm`

Comment: The brcmfmac modules don't seem to be in my installation. Modinfo exits with an error that the module brcmfmac is not found.

Comment: When you installed the 4.16 kernel, did you also install *linux-image-extras*? That's where most all of the loadable modules will be found.

Comment: No, it seems that would be installed with the kernel package from Ubuntu sources. I cloned the RockMyy repository, which seems to directly clone the Linux repository from Linux and apply some patches. Would the package still work or would I have to install the kernel from Ubuntu sources and then install the _linux-image-extras_ package?

Comment: Sorry, I know nothing about your Asus nor the RockMyy process.